# Stack Overflow jobs - removed experience

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I was editing my Stack Overflow Jobs page.  I saw against an experience I had added for a previous job, buttons for 'edit', 'remove' and a drop-down arrow.  Curiously I hit the arrow and it was actually just the 'remove' and gone was the experience.
No confirmation was presented *`do you really want to do this`* and as far as I can tell it has gone.

Is there any history or a way to get this back?

Can the UI be improved so this will not happen to other users?

Comment: Another bug!  I added a new tag 'career' and it was changed to 'career-development' (also new).

Comment: I've voted to migrate this question to Meta Stack Overflow, which is the appropriate location for questions about the site itself, including Careers/Jobs.

Comment: That tag change was not a bug; [career] is a tag synonym for [career-development] here on Stack Overflow (though both tags are deprecated at this point). On meta there will be a [careers] or [jobs] tag that you can used instead.

Comment: You may be confused about what happened (I agree that the UI is not as clear as it could be, but note that a massive resign of Jobs is underway). The down arrow does **not** delete the entry, it just re-orders it to be further down the page. Check and see if it's still there. When I press "remove", I *am* asked for confirmation.

Comment: Cool I'm happy with the move to Meta - makes sense.  Glad to see it wasn't deleted.  Maybe an up and down arrow next to each other would make it clear about its function.  With one being unavailable for the first or last post.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. That would be clearer. It does look like a drop down now.

Comment: @Zanon I expect my customers and colleagues to stop at 5?s rather than 6.  6 is just excessive.

Comment: @Zanon I also expect to be paid when I'm the developer, but I won't start charging people to answer their questions...

Comment: @JeremyBanks Shouldn't that be an answer rather than just a comment?